# Python getattr in string

Tags: python, getattr

I have a string `x = 'hello world'`, and I'm trying to uppercase it with `getattr()`

I understand that `getattr(x, 'upper')` returns `x.upper`, which is different from `x.upper()`, and then returns `<built-in method upper of str object at 0x7fd26eb0e2b0>`

I also understand that, using `getattr(str, 'upper)(x)`, I can get the desired result, `'HELLO WORLD'`

But why and how can I get the uppercase `x` calling `getattr(x, 'upper')`, passing `x`, and not `str` class, as a parameter? Is it possible? And why?

Comment: getattr will return you the method. you need to add pranthesis to execute that method. `getattr(x, 'upper')()`

Comment: You are missing the significance of `getattr(x, 'upper')` returning `x.upper`. Both are simply expressions that evaluate to a `method` object, which is what gets called with `()`. `getattr(x, 'upper')()` and `x.upper()` are equivalent as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the returned function:

```
x = 'hello world'
getattr(x, 'upper')()  # note the extra "()"
# 'HELLO WORLD'
```

With the given information, you don't need `getattr` at all and could just use `x.upper()`. As you might be in a dynamic context where you would have to call possibly multiple methods on multiple strings, you may be interested in `operator.methodcaller` and `operator.attrgetter` which might make some of your code more reusable:

```
from operator import attrgetter, methodcaller

up = methodcaller("upper")
up(x)
'HELLO WORLD'
up("foo")
'FOO'

up2 = attrgetter("upper")
up2(x)()
'HELLO WORLD'
```

Comment: Aah! Understood! Then, the argument of `upper()` is implicit, being `x` itself! Thank you @schwobaseggl

Comment: Kind of. `str.upper` evaluates to an instance of `function`. `x.upper` evaluates to an instance of `method` (and that instance contains references to both `str.upper` and `x`).